# change zip file comment on the fly in php

Tags: php, zip, archive

I want to change zip file comment on the fly.

I read the file like this :

```
$file         = file_get_contents($download_url);
```

and I send it to the user without saving the file temporarily. (using headers .... )

I want to know is it possible to change zip file comment without saving it temporarily?

Comment: PHP built in library does not have functions to open a string buffer as zip file, but you can write to /dev/shm which on modern Linux is in ram and read it back

Comment: I don't have root access to the server. if you know a third-party library for that matter. I will appreciate it. thanks in advance

Comment: /dev/shm is like /tmp - anybody can write it it usually